# Add audio as clickable to background image

Tags: audio

Old code is

```
<p><img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;" src="jim.jpg" alt="" /></p>

<audio autoplay=""> <source src="horn.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>`
```

`

Chrome disabled audio playing by default on pages back in 2018, want to make the image clickable instead to play a the sound

Comment: Sorry, its probably something dead simple but I have more of an HTML background and don't know enough JavaScript to figure out what I'm doing wrong when I try various methods I've googled and found here so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.